# Issuse with recursion and the "input()" function in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, validation, recursion

I am having a problem, I have function that takes input and returns True if the input is "yes", False if it is "no", and calls its self if the input is something else. Here is my code:

```
def call_from_Zeus():
    system("cls||clear")
    call_from_Zeus_string = """     ___ _  _  ___ ___  __  __ ___ _  _  ___    ___   _   _    _     
    |_ _| \| |/ __/ _ \|  \/  |_ _| \| |/ __|  / __| /_\ | |  | |    
     | || .` | (_| (_) | |\/| || || .` | (_ | | (__ / _ \| |__| |__  
    |___|_|\_|\___\___/|_|  |_|___|_|\_|\___|  \___/_/ \_\____|____| 


                    \33[1;37;49mFROM: \33[1;34;49mMr.Zeus[ADMIN\33[1;33;49m+\33[1;34;49m]\33[0m

                    \33[1;37;49mTO: USER#8009395797394869
    \33[0m
    """
    print(call_from_Zeus_string)
    in1 = input('\t       Accept Call(Enter "yes" or "no")? ')
    if in1 == "yes" or in1 == "Yes" or in1 == "YES" or in1 == "y":
        return True
    elif in1 == "no" or in1 == "No" or in1 == "NO" or in1 == "n":
        return False
    else:
        del in1
        call_from_Zeus()
```

The code its self does not crash, but if the input is invalid it calls its self no matter what you enter it resorts to the `else:` statement.
I have no idea what is going on. As you can see I even tried `del`ing the `in1` variable. Thanks for any help in advance!

-Zeus

Comment: Can't reproduce; the code works for me.

Comment: Also you recursively call `call_from_Zeus` but discard its value. Try `return`ing it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what value I should return.

Comment: In the else clause, `return call_from_Zeus()`

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: YAY, It worked thanks so much! Oh, by the way is it a good practice to delete the `in1` variable?

Comment: @Mr.Zeus No, don't delete it. Also, don't do input validation via recursion might not be the best way to do things, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for alternatives.

Comment: Wow that is very helpful @L3viathan! Thanks for the link! We all learn new things every day (especial ppl. like me who have less than 6 months of coding under their belt).